# operations on rows of a pandas dataframe which columns have the same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe as:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Start': [0,  71,  0,  0,  12, 56],
                      'End': [70, 88,  10, 11, 55, 90],
                    'Value': [1,  0,   1,  1,  0,  1],
                     'Name': ['A','A', 'B','C','C','C']},
                      index =[0,  1,   2,  3,  4,  5])
```

For each Name ('A','B','C')
I want to compute some operations...

How can I do the following in a more pythonic way?

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['value1','value2','value3'])


unique_names = list(df1['Name'].unique())

for name in unique_names:

    df=df1.loc[df1['Name'] == name]

    value1 = operation1(df)
    value2 = operation2(df)
    value3 = operation3(df)            

    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(np.array([value1,value2,value3]).reshape(-1,3),columns=['value1','value2','value3'])
    df3 = pd.concat([df3, df_temp], ignore_index=True)[df3.columns.tolist()]
```

Answer (score 0):

this is where `df.groupby().apply()` would come in.

Say for example your three operations were as follows:

```
#get sum of all Start values
operation1 = lambda x: x.Start.sum()
#get sum of all End values
operation2 = lambda x: x.End.sum()
#get mean of Values
operation3 = lambda x: x.Value.mean()
```

you can acheive exactly what you're after in one operation:

```
df3 = df1.groupby('Name').apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(
        [operation1(x), operation2(x), operation3(x)],
        index=['value1','value2','value3']
    ))
```

Returns:

```
    value1  value2  value3
Name            
A   71.0    158.0   0.500000
B   0.0     10.0    1.000000
C   68.0    156.0   0.666667
```